# compare json result which is date feted from mysql to system current date and show result in textview

Tags: android, mysql, json

Well I have done lots of research for this but unfortunately I didn't get any clue or example or hint for this .
I have stored several date in mysql. I have successfully fetched my data in json format .
Now I want to compare my by-default mobile date to the json result if my system date matches with json result it shows the value in textview .
Please help me in this .
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what u have tried and what is the issue ?

Comment: @piyush I didn't understand how to proceed .

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to write a code for this in any language
eg. PHP.

1. Need to connect with MYsql
2. fetch result
3. Parse json
4. Compare that date key node with System date
5. Finally show data.